# Google Maps Marker in the wrong position

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am struggling to understand this.

My code is below along with a link to a test page showing the map
with marker in the wrong place.

I have set the lat and lng consistent with 
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Dakota+Hotel+Eurocentral/@55.8353173,-3.9854019,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4888441f8bb5be07:0x6444cfc231481afe!8m2!3d55.8353173!4d-3.9832132

As you can see from the link they are 55.8353173 and -3.9854019

However when I include them in my code below - the marker appears in the wrong place.
See http://craigfagan.com/queenslie/testmap.html

My code is below.

Any help would be greatly appreciate on this - Scratching my head wondering what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any advice..

```
<div id="map"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 17,
   scrollwheel: false,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8353173,-3.9854019),
   styles: 
[{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"color":"#d3d3d3"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":
[{"color":"#808080"},{"visibility":"off"}]},  
{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke",
"stylers":
[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#b3b3b3"}]},
{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},
{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"weight":1.8}]},
{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":
[{"color":"#d7d7d7"}]},
{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ebebeb"}]},
{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry","stylers":
[{"color":"#a7a7a7"}]},
{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},
{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},
{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#efefef"}]},
{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":
[{"color":"#696969"}]}, 
 {"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill",
"stylers":
[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#737373"}]},
{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":
[{"visibility":"off"}]},
{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":
[{"visibility":"off"}]},
{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke",
"stylers":
[{"color":"#d6d6d6"}]},
{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":
[{"visibility":"off"}]},{},
{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":
[{"color":"#dadada"}]}]
   };

var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8353173,-3.9854019),
   map: map,
   title: 'Dakota'
});

 }
 </script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
 key=AIzaSyDJRdPso7qlkubRB66DafdHiBClCZoGGsI&callback=initMap" async 
 defer></script>
```

Comment: The coordinates in the link are the center of the map, not the marker.

Comment: Thanks - do you know how I get the co-ordinates of the marker?

Comment: There are several ways, the first question is do you want to use Google Maps or the Places API to get the coordinates?

Comment: Thanks - I've got a deadline - so whatever is easier?

Comment: In Google Maps, right click on the icon of the place, click "what's here", it will give you the coordinates (55.835326,-3.983235 for that example).  If I use the Places API (for "Dakota Hotel Eurocentral"), I get (55.8353173,-3.983213200000023), which is better.

Comment: This is excellent - thanks so much geocodezip

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates in the link after the @ sign are the center of the map, not the marker.

To get the center of the map in Google Maps, right click on the icon of the place, click "what's here", it will give you the coordinates (55.835326,-3.983235 for that example).

If I use the Places API (for "Dakota Hotel Eurocentral"), I get (55.8353173,-3.983213200000023), which is better.